# How to decompile ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application that runs on ASP.NET. The code which was developed in C# is compiled. The company that originally wrote the application is no longer trading. We now need to make changes to the functionality of the application, and of course we can;t because of the source code is compiled.

Is there a way to decompile all of this code so that we can work with it?

Comment: While your question is a duplicate, I'd recommend using `IL Spy`, `Just Decoompile` or `dotPeek` instead of .NET Reflector. Reflector used to be a great tool but after Red Gate acquired it its quality plummeted. The other tools are also free.

Comment: Indeed. .NET Reflector is utter garbage (now).

Comment: I'll also vote for JustDecompile http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx. Of course, you'll have a lot of work to do since the compilation process can rename things, and the dll may also be obfuscated as well.